# method/function undefined inside map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
contructor:
this.getMeSomething = this.getMeSomething.bind(this)//////


getMeSomething(abc, xyz, event){}


class xyz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ ...}}>
                    {
                    this.props.cars.map((car) => {
                        return <div><span className="yhn"><label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething(this, this.props.color, car)} /><span></span></label>{car}</span></div>
                        })
                    }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Error at

```
<div><span className="yhn"><label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething(this, this.props.color, car)} /><span></span></label>{car}</span></div>
```

execution.

this is showing as window and getMeSomething is coming as undefined. Not sure what is wrong in the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMeSomething` needs to be defined inside the class to use it with `this`.

```
    class xyz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.getMeSomething = this.getMeSomething.bind(this)
  }

  getMeSomething(event){}

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ ...}}>
            {
            this.props.cars.map((car) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <span className="yhn">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething} />
                    </label>
                    {car}
                  </span>
                </div>
                )
              })
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want `getMeSomething` to be outside the class, then another way is to pass it as `props`. Avoid attaching it to the global `window` object.

Also `this` is implicitly available within `getMeSomething` and so are `props`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working. instead of binding in the constructor, I bounded it at the onChange event something like this. <div><span className="yhn"><label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething.bind(this, this.props.color, car)} /><span></span></label>{car}</span></div>.   But, I have couple of more questions on this, what do you mean by --> Avoid attaching it to the global window object. --> Also this is implicitly available within getMeSomething and so are props.

Comment: When invoking `this.getMeSomething.bind(this, this.props.color, car)`, you are passing `this.props.color` as an argument. Its not needed. Within the function itself `this.props` is available to you since `getMeSomething` bound to the `class`

Comment: gotcha Thanks @Hozefa  One more question:  what do you mean by --> Avoid attaching it to the global window object.

Comment: In your code snippet it looks like `getMeSomething` is bound the global `window` object and not the class itself. Once you have `getMeSomething` inside the class, you are fine.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what is going on at the top of the code sample.  I am reading it as the method getMeSomething is defined outside of the class xyz.  Therefore, it would be undefined for class xyz, which the this keyword is pointing to.  Comment, or edit the code sample if I am reading it wrong.  The solution is to move it within the class, or to not refer to it using the this keyword.

```
class xyz extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    // Move here
    getMeSomething(abc, xyz, event){}

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ ...}}>
                    {
                        // Value of this is the class xyz
                    this.props.cars.map((car) => {
                        // Lambda functions keeps value of this as same as outer scope, so still class xyz.
                        return <div><span className="yhn"><label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething(this, this.props.color, car)} /><span></span></label>{car}</span></div>
                        })
                    }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, here is a refactored solution that avoids having to use bind and simplifies your render template logic.  It appears to be working in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfleming/h050jh9x/20/).

```
class CarsComponent extends React.Component {

    getMeSomething(car, isChecked) {
        console.log(isChecked); // True or False
        console.log(car); // Car that was clicked - ex: 'Honda' 
        console.log(this.props.colors); // [ 'blue', 'green', 'yellow' ]
    }

    renderCars(car) {
        return this.props.cars.map((car, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <span className="yhn">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.getMeSomething(car, e.target.checked)} />
                            <span>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        {car}
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderCars() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Test prop variables, you will car your own notion of what these are.
const cars = [ 'Honda', 'Toyota' ];
const colors = [ 'blue', 'green', 'yellow' ];

ReactDOM.render(
    <CarsComponent cars={cars} colors={colors}/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Hi William, the above seems to be working except I had to add binding stuff. if possible, can you answer the questions from my end in the above comment.

Comment: Okay, let me get an environment setup so I can test for myself.

Comment: See if the above solution works for you.  The fiddle will show it in action, just open the console to see the log statements.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. That seems to be working. Just a small question, is there any use of not using bind. Also, suppose if I want to use state variable defined in constructor of other class, is there a way apart from passing it through props to this class?

Comment: No problem! For me, it is a personal preference.  It adds complexity where it can be avoided.  I actually prefer not to use the "this" keyword when I can.  In class based components in React, there is no real way around that though.  Anyways, all that to say, your solution was not wrong.  It is just my personal preference for code readability.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again! That showed me a new way to solve it.